# Phonegap Softkeyboard covers input field

Tags: android, cordova

The softkeyboard in my Phonegap 3.1 covers the input field in my Android 4.x. This problem has been very annoying and I almost posted a question just now. But suddenly there is the spark, I integrated answers from multiple posts on Stackoverflow and got the right solution. I just want to post it here for future reference.
There are two key steps:

1. Go to your config.xml, disable fullscreen mode: (many posts omitted this part)

> `<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false">`

2.In config.xml, add the following line:

> `<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize">`

Alternatively, if you are using the SDK, you may go to your project's AndroidManifest.xml and add:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the attribute of `<activity>`

The above two lines of code should have the same effect after your build the app with phonegap.

Then run your app, keyboard should not be covering your input any more.

Feel free to add anything if the solution does not work for you.

Comment: Clarification: This is not exactly a question, but a solution about a few questions of the same type. I've seen several posts about Softkeyboard covering input fields in Phonegap apps but no one has provided a complete solution for my Android development needs. I left my solution which was compiled from several posts here for anyone who is looking for a complete solution in the future.