# Automatic scroll to end of scrollable-content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive

I face a common problem with the native keyboard of smartphone devices. 
Basically we have a list with a input field at the end. So, the list in a scrollable-content class where you can scroll without problem. But if you want to enter a text in the last input field, the keyboard pops up and hide it.

Is there a possibility to automatic scroll to the item? I figured out the $uiViewScroll but it don't worked very well in my directive.

```
(function(){
'use strict';

 angular.module('directive.scroll', [])
 .directive('topScroll', ['$uiViewScroll', function($uiViewScroll){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      $uiViewScroll(element);
    }
  }
 }]);
})();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found the solution in this post. It is pretty easy with the directive. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22407177/2151532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.

In your **config.xml** , if you have :

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

change it to :

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

Comment: just found this link, it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874170/phonegap-softkeyboard-covers-input-field?rq=1